# Copy multiple files and append to end of filename

Tags: bash, cp

Seems like I really shouldn't need to create a script for this. I'd like to do something `cp /etc/*.conf $1.orig` or `cp /etc/{a.conf,b.conf} _firstarg_.orig` Is there a quick and painless way of doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's easy with a loop:

```
for f in /etc/*.conf; do cp -v -- "$f" "$f.orig"; done
```

Comment: that'll work. For some reason I doesn't feel like bash would make us do a for loop as the simplest and quickest way, but whatever it works!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: To me it's easier this way : `find . -name "*text*" -exec cp {} {}_addedtext \;`

Answer (score 1):

[In any shell, you can use a loop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10856/copy-multiple-files-and-append-to-end-of-filename/10859#10859):

```
for x in /etc/*.conf; do cp -i -- "$x" "$x.orig"; done
```

(Remove `-i` if you don't care about overwriting existing files.)

With zsh, you can use the provided function `zcm` (put the first three lines in your `~/.zshrc`):

```
autoload zmv
alias zcp='zmv -C'
alias zln='zmv -L'
zcp '/etc/(*.conf)' '/etc/$1.orig'
```

(Add `-f` after `zcp` to overwrite any existing destination file.)